# how can i solve Undefined offset: 2 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined offset: 2
Filename: controllers/mycontrollers.php
Line Number: 721
how i solve it?

CODE:

```
$serial_number_array = json_decode($this->input->post('serial_number_array_session'));
        if (isset($serial_number_array)) {
                if ($serial_number_array == null) {                   
                } else {
                    $Serial_number_info_array = array();
                    foreach ($serial_number_array as $value) {
                        $Serial_number_info_array['Issue_Number'] = $Issue;
                        $Serial_number_info_array['status_serial_item'] = 1;
                        $Item_name = $value->Item_Name_session;
                        for ($a = 0; $a <= $loop_serial_number; $a++) {
                            ***$serial_number = $value->serial_number_session["$a"];***
                            $this->Inventory_model->Update_serial_number_model($Item_name,$serial_number,$Serial_number_info_array);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: your `$loop_serial_number` is no where define and you are using it in `for` loop? It will give you error

Comment: i think you don't have the array length up to 3, and you are trying to access that index

Comment: And, Change `$serial_number = $value->serial_number_session["$a"];` to `$serial_number = $value->serial_number_session[$a];`

Comment: i do that:
$serial_number = $value->serial_number_session[$a];
But same error show.

Comment: Then, what about @AlivetoDie Question's?

Comment: i could not understand what you say about @AlivetoDie Question's?

Comment: *..your $loop_serial_number is no where define and you are using it in for loop?* From where, `$loop_serial_number` coming into picture?

Comment: @golammoktadir replace your for loop with this `for ($a = 0; $a <= $loop_serial_number; $a++) { if ( isset($value->serial_number_session["$a"]) ) { $serial_number = $value->serial_number_session["$a"]; $this->Inventory_model->Update_serial_number_model($Item_name,$serial_number,$Serial_number_info_array); } else { /*else part of code*/ }  }` it will work fine.

Comment: Its a little messy in the comment but you should give it a try :)

Comment: Hey I updated your question - (updated the for loop only) have a look and may it works for you.